# When I multiply these numbers the output is not what I intended

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
     ArrayList<Integer> distances = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    distances.add(70);
    distances.add(113);
    distances.add(1);
    distances.add(1700000000);
    distances.add(268000);
    int i =0;       
    while(n-->0 & i<5)
    {

        int distance = distances.get(i);

        int au = distance * (149597871 * 1000);
        System.out.println(au);
        i++;
    }
}
```

> So my code outputs this:

```
720702352
-431854056
-725984360
444733440
-1789971200
```

> But the output should be this:

```
10471850970000
16904559423000
149597871000
254316380700000000000 
40092229428000000
```

> So my question is how do I fix this issue because I do not understand why it is giving me the wrong product. FYI, if you plug the equation into a calculator it works.

Comment: You're overflowing your integers.  They only go up to 2 billion or so.

Comment: FYI you should almost always use `&&` for boolean operations.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll look at that problem. Sorry. Also thanks for that reminder about the boolean operations.

Comment: Integers can only have a max value of **2147483647** and a minimum value of **-2147483648**. You could I  suppose try a Long data type but then again, it can only support a max value of **9223372036854775807** and a minimum value of **-9223372036854775808**. Even this may not be big enough to support some of your calculations. 

You need to use the [BigInteger Class](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/). This should support whatever you need to do.